# jquerymobile refiltering

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquerymobile. And on a list I have a filter. When a user types something in it filters great. However when I add more items to the list, then the filtering does not refresh.

Any idea how I can refresh the filtering? (re-filter the list?)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trigger a change event on the search input field like this after items are added to list.

```
$(".ui-input-search .ui-input-text").trigger("change");
```

A sample:

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
       $("#btn").live("click",function(){
            $("#list").append("<li><a href='#'>100</a></li><li><a href='#'>200</a></li><li><a href='#'>400</a></li><li><a href='#'>500</a></li><li><a href='#'>1000</a></li>");
            $("#list").listview("refresh");
            $("#page").trigger("create");
            $(".ui-input-search .ui-input-text").trigger("change");
       });
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="page" data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content"> 
    <ul id="list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">41</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">91</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">65</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a data-role="button" id="btn">Add more</a>
</div>
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>

</html>
```

Demo - http://pastehtml.com/view/bnl7lpe3o.html

Let me know if that helps.

**Update for jQuery Mobile 1.4**
The filter behavior has been separated out into a `filterable` widget. You can update your listview content and rerun the filter in one swipe:

```
$( ".listselector" ).filterable( "refresh" );
```

A nice benefit of this is that the list items are filtered immediately. You do not experience the visual glitch of seeing the items for a split second before they get filtered, as you would when manually triggering the input control.
See http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/#method-refresh

The code above would no longer work, because jQuery Mobile keeps track of the last text entered into the filter, and does not filter if the input has not changed. If you *did* want to trigger the input control, you would need the following hack to first clear the last entered input:

```
$(".ui-input-search input").attr('data-lastval', '').trigger("change");
```

But, please use the `filterable` function going forward.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem should be resolved with `refresh` method, but I am not sure:

```
$('#mylist').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: jQM Docs on the listview method http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

Answer (score 1):

After updating the list view, adding the below code will refresh the contents so that it becomes visible :

```
$("#list").listview("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides using the previously mentioned listview refresh, take note that using jQuery's `.show()` on a listitem will cause `display:block;` to be added to the element's CSS. Because it takes precedence over jQM's `ui-screen-hidden` class, it interferes with the searchfilter's ability to hide items when they don't match.

So if you are adding items to the list by way of `.show()`/`.hide()` combos, use `.css('display','')` instead of `.show()`.

My general order for adding new hidden items:

```
// 1. Clear display:none and display:block, if necessary, from the listitem
$(yourLI).css('display','');
// 2. Apply jQM formatting, such as corners and other CSS, to the entire listview
$(yourListView).listview('refresh');
// 3. Make sure the searchfilter runs on the new items without user intervention
$(".ui-input-search .ui-input-text").trigger("change");
```