# jquerymobile listview filter programmatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to accomplish this task.

I have two columns grid

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:35%">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a href="#" data-role="button">A</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">B</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">C</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">D</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">E</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">F</a>
        </div>        
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a href="#" data-role="button">G</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">H</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">I</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">J</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">K</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">L</a>
        </div> 
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a href="#" data-role="button">M</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">N</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">Ñ</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">O</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">P</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">Q</a>
        </div> 
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a href="#" data-role="button">R</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">S</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">T</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">U</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">V</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">W</a>
        </div>         
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a href="#" data-role="button">X</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">Y</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button">Z</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="buscar();">BUSCAR</a>
        </div>         
    </div>       
    <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:65%; top:0; position:relative;">
        <ul id ="milista" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" style="left:1em; width:95%; ">
            <li><a href="index.html">Acura</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Audi</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">BMW</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Cadillac</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Chrysler</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Dodge</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Ferrari</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Ford</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">GMC</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Honda</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Hyundai</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Infiniti</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Jeep</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Kia</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Lexus</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Mini</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Nissan</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Porsche</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Subaru</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Toyota</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Volkswagon</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Volvo</a></li>
        </ul>        
    </div>
</div>
```

like shows at http://jsfiddle.net/jupagose/sugfP/,  I want to programmatically filter the listview while the user type's on lefthand panel.  I don't want to force the user to load  OS keyboard.

It is possible with jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go :

```
  $("[data-role=button]").click(function(e){
        var filter_el = $(".ui-input-text");
        var filter_val = filter_el.val();
        var filter_query = filter_val+$(this).text();
        filter_el.val(filter_query);
        filter_el.trigger("change")
    });
```

Ideally, I would add a class to each button and use that class for the button click event
e.g. `$(".keyboard-btn").click ...` the same goes for the filter.

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sugfP/14/ ​

**UPDATE:**

Here's an example of using keyboard classes:
http://jsfiddle.net/sugfP/15/

Comment: Definitely, the best people are at stackoverflow, very tks, it's exactly what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Richard's answer is perfect, but there's an update for JQM 1.4.

[jquerymobile refiltering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213992/jquerymobile-refiltering).

Just triggering "change" event wont filter the list. You would have to rather separetly call "filterable" widget and its "refresh" method

```
$(".listselector").filterable("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple inputs, using

```
ui-input-text
```

will select all of them.
use this instead to only pick the filter

```
var filter_el = $("[data-type='search']");
```